# Play Framework: Dependency Injection inside Action

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, guice

Short version: how to inject an object inside Action in Play Framework?

Long version: In my project I have custom annotation action `@AuthenticationRequired` which loads `User` object from the database and puts it into `context.args`. It uses DAO class that implements `UserDAO`. Now I want to use DAO class injected into `Action` by Google Guice. I can use Guice and inject instances in controllers and tests, but I have difficulties injecting DAO class inside Action.

Injector is a field on `GlobalSettings` instance.

I tried to override `GlobalSettings#onRequest()` and put UserDAO instance to `context.args` and then retrieve it from inside `AuthenticationRequired` action, but it turns out that Action returned by `GlobalSettings#onRequest()` being called last in the chain of action used with @With and/or custom annotations, so, it is to late.

I also tried to inject DAO instance by annotating action constructor, but but it uses no-args constructor to create an instance of action.

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

For play 2.5 you can simply add @Inject on top of the constructor of Action class and inject whatever needed. Here is a snippet from my working project (I'm using Guice as DI):

```
public class ChannelPermissionAction extends Action<ChannelPermission> {

  private final AuthorizationService authorizationService;
  private final AsyncHelper asyncHelper;

  @Inject
  public ChannelPermissionAction(AuthorizationService authorizationService, AsyncHelper asyncHelper) {
     this.authorizationService = authorizationService;
     this.asyncHelper = asyncHelper;
  }
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this just the same as with controllers - describe your action as (a bean in my case - i'm using spring IoC) a dependency and get it called by

```
public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> clazz)
```

of [Application Global object](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaGlobal#The-Global-object). That's all you need - you'r dependencies would be injected.
BTW. Actions need to be created with each instance so in my case I should use "prototype" scope.
Mind it while using Guice - it should have similar functionality.

Comment: Do you mean that if I define action as a property of my controller (+annotating it with `@Inject` and passing it as a parameter to the constructor) then the same instance will be used as Controller action?

Comment: I meant that if you annotating your controller with your action annotation like [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaActionsComposition#Annotating-controllers) than your action would be instantiated with DI container (and it's dependencies) just before your controller. DI Container will inject your action's dependencies and you'll be free to use those at your action code